# What does this mean in c++?

Tags: c++, string, char

```
chk[c - 'A'] = true;
```

What does this mean in c++?
I was trying to solve palindrome reorder but i cant't understand this part.

Here is the full code:

```
int cnt = 0;
bool chk[26];
string s, ans = "";

int main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);
    cin >> s;
    for (char& c : s) {
        if (!chk[c - 'A']) {
            chk[c - 'A'] = true;
            cnt++;
        }
        else {
            ans += c;
            chk[c - 'A'] = false;
            cnt--;
        }
    }
    if (cnt >= 2) {
        cout << "NO SOLUTION" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    cout << ans;
    for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++) {
        if (chk[c - 'A']) {
            cout << c;
        }
    }
    reverse(ans.begin(), ans.end());
    cout << ans;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *i was trying to solve palindrome reorder* -- So you are using the C++ language to solve this problem, and not know the basics of the computer language you're using?

Comment: `chk` appears to be an array or some container of boolean values where chk[0] represents the character `A`.

Comment: If you got this question about "palindrome reorder" from one of those online coding competition sites, please note that the questions asked on those sites assume you know the computer language you will be using.  Those sites are not a substitute for learning C++.

Comment: This is an assignment expression.

Comment: Presumably, `c` is an integer. When you subtract `'A'` from it, you are effectively subtracting 65 from `c` (65 is the ASCII code for `A`). Then, you use this resulting integer to index what is presumably an array `chk` and you assign the value `true` at that position in the array.

Comment: for (char &c : s)
    {
        if (!chk[c - 'A'])
        {
            chk[c - 'A'] = true;
            cnt++;
        }

Comment: @DeepakSilver don't post code in a comment, it's unreadable. Instead [edit] your question. Also take the [tour] and read this: [ask]

Comment: The first loop appears to make sure that an upper case letter has been seen exactly 2 times before it adds it to the ans. When this happens it also resets the count to allow it to be added again if the letter appears twice again.

Answer (score 3):

The characters `[A-Z]` have values `65-90` respectively in the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/), `c - 'A'` "normalizes" each of `[A-Z]` to `[0, 25]` to fit in `bool chk[]` which I assume had a size of 26 to keep track of existing upper-case letters in a string to *reorder the palindrome*.

A better way of doing this would be using a modern C++ container like `std::unordered_map`:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::unordered_map <char, bool> letterExists;
    std::string str;
    for (auto c : str)
        letterExists[c] = true;
}
```